# Empty values inside array - VBA

Tags: vba

Hi I have a cubic spline interpolation function and I am struggling to use it when I have empty cells either on vector x or y. In other others I need both arrays to "condensate" keeping correspondence to each other either if the X vector or Y vector contains empty values. Can you guys help me please ?

Ex:
please see example here

[image]

```
x   5   28  49  empty   empty   111 133 153 171 194 214 235 256

y   2.15    2.154   2.11    2.09    2.065   2.065   2.05    empty   empty   2.21    2.354   2.347   2.45
```

vectors should be:

```
x   5   28  49  111 133 194 214 235 256

y   2.15    2.154   2.11    2.065   2.05    2.21    2.354   2.347   2.45
```

code

```
Public Function CubicSplineH(ByVal Xarray As Range, ByVal Yarray As Range, ByVal q As Double)

Dim period_count As Integer
Dim rate_count As Integer
period_count = Xarray.Columns.Count
rate_count = Yarray.Columns.Count
If period_count <> rate_count Then
    CubicSplineH = "Error: Range count dos not match"
    GoTo endnow
End If
 
ReDim Xin(period_count) As Single
ReDim Yin(period_count) As Single
Dim C As Integer
For C = 1 To period_count
Xin(C) = Xarray(C)
Yin(C) = Yarray(C)
Next C
Dim N As Integer
Dim i, K As Integer
Dim P, qn, sig, un As Single
ReDim u(period_count - 1) As Single
ReDim yt(period_count) As Single
N = period_count
yt(1) = 0
u(1) = 0
For i = 2 To N - 1
    sig = (Xin(i) - Xin(i - 1)) / (Xin(i + 1) - Xin(i - 1))
    P = sig * yt(i - 1) + 2
    yt(i) = (sig - 1) / P
    u(i) = (Yin(i + 1) - Yin(i)) / (Xin(i + 1) - Xin(i)) - (Yin(i) - Yin(i - 1)) / (Xin(i) - Xin(i - 1))
    u(i) = (6 * u(i) / (Xin(i + 1) - Xin(i - 1)) - sig * u(i - 1)) / P
    
    Next i
    
qn = 0
un = 0
yt(N) = (un - qn * u(N - 1)) / (qn * yt(N - 1) + 1)
For K = N - 1 To 1 Step -1
    yt(K) = yt(K) * yt(K + 1) + u(K)
Next K
Dim klo, khi As Integer
Dim h, b, a As Single
Dim y As Double

klo = 1
khi = N
Do
K = khi - klo
If Xin(K) > q Then
khi = K
Else
klo = K
End If
K = khi - klo
Loop While K > 1
h = Xin(khi) - Xin(klo)
a = (Xin(khi) - q) / h
b = (q - Xin(klo)) / h
y = a * Yin(klo) + b * Yin(khi) + ((a ^ 3 - a) * yt(klo) + (b ^ 3 - b) * yt(khi)) * (h ^ 2) / 6

CubicSplineH = y
endnow:

End Function
```

Comment: Do you have a test routine that calls `CubicSplineH` and the data it uses to produce your output? If cells are being skipped when creating the output, the error is more likely in that bit of code.

Comment: i think blank cells are included with zero as value, which creates incorrect values

Comment: Why the mixed types? Excel native numbers are `Double` and not `Single` and the native integer type is actually `Long` and not `Integer`. In VBA `Integer` is a 16-bit signed integer that goes up to 36767 and then it overflows.

Comment: The hole subroutine isn't needed for the question. What you are _really_ asking is **hot to convert a range with empty cells to a dense array** for use in math.

Comment: I honestly don't know John, thanks for highlighting. I'm still learning, I've got this code which I use to interpolate interest rates using a cubic spline function, I didn't write it. 
I wanted to adapt it to a dense array as you said. Maybe I should re write it from scratch, I just don't how to do that yet.

Comment: @Thomas - I have written the exact same code in VBA (based on Numerical Methods Book) and ended up writing a class that can be initialized from either ranges or arrays of values. But I never considered missing values before.

Comment: @Thomas - [here is a link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_vMJd-xwDIsWHJtdUp6RFdOUjg/view?usp=sharing) to my code that interpolates data using cubic spline. The driving routine is the code for `Sheet1`. **It does not handle gaps in the data**

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim nArrayCount As Long
    Dim rngX As Range
    Dim rngY As Range
    Dim xArray() As Long
    Dim yArray() As Double
    Dim indexer As Long
    Dim iterator As Long
    
    'This is the range of values, to be condensed
    Set rngX = Range("A1:M1")
    Set rngY = Range("A2:M2")
    
    'Start with the width of the range, including blank.
    'The code assumes that both x and y range have the same
    'number of cells. If this isn't the case, you may
    'need some logic to support that.
    nArrayCount = rngX.Columns.Count
    
    'Resize the array to the full width of the range
    ReDim xArray(nArrayCount)
    ReDim yArray(nArrayCount)
    
    'Init the indexer to 0 or 1 (depending on what base
    'you are using for your arrays)
    indexer = 1
    
    For i = 0 To nArrayCount - 1
        If rngX.Range("A1").Offset(, i).Value <> "" _
            And rngY.Range("A1").Offset(, i).Value <> "" Then
            
            xArray(indexer) = rngX.Range("A1").Offset(, i).Value
            yArray(indexer) = rngY.Range("A1").Offset(, i).Value
            
            indexer = indexer + 1
        End If
    Next i
    
    'Now that the array has been filled, redimension it
    'to remove any of the empty elements
    ReDim Preserve xArray(indexer - 1)
    ReDim Preserve yArray(indexer - 1)
    
    'Just a test to make sure it worked
    For i = LBound(xArray) To UBound(xArray)
        Debug.Print xArray(i) & " --> " & yArray(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

The output would be two arrays, with corresponding elements:

```
5 --> 2.15
28 --> 2.154
49 --> 2.11
111 --> 2.065
133 --> 2.05
194 --> 2.21
214 --> 2.354
235 --> 2.347
236 --> 2.45
```

The below code will create an array, sized to the input range while ignoring blanks. I commented it to steer you in the right direction. Take a look and let us know if it get's you in the right direction.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim nArrayCount As Long
    Dim inputRange As Range
    Dim theArray() As Long
    Dim indexer As Long
    Dim cel As Range
    
    'This is the range of values, to be condensed
    Set inputRange = Range("A1:M1")
    
    'Determine the number of non-blank elements in the range
    nArrayCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(inputRange)
    ReDim theArray(nArrayCount)
    
    'Init the indexer to 0 or 1 (depending on what base
    'you are using for your arrays)
    indexer = 1
    
    'Loop over the entire range, ignoring the blanks
    For Each cel In inputRange
        If cel.Value <> "" Then
            theArray(indexer) = cel.Value
            
            'increment the indexer
            indexer = indexer + 1
        End If
    Next cel
    
    'Just a test to make sure it worked
    For i = LBound(theArray) To UBound(theArray)
        Debug.Print theArray(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: would this wrap BOTH arrays? if one value is missing from both X and Y arrays both arrays should be reduced keeping correspondence. 
any ways, I will study what you sent me...thanks for this

Comment: @Thomas, I misunderstood the original request. I thought you just wanted each of the arrays to remove the blanks. If you want to only include items where items in the same column BOTH don't have blanks, I'm editing my post to include a different subroutine as well as the output. I think it would be more easily adapted to your needs.

Comment: you are very good, thank you very much for this I really appreciate it. all the best
i will try to adapt my code now